# GDataServiceGoogleDocs

Tags: ios, xcode, google-docs, gdata-api, google-docs-api

I am currently incorporating GData with Objective-C, specifically I am trying out Google Docs API.
However, I have been running into the following issue as I compile:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleDocs", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GDataViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataQueryDocs", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GDataViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I have searched many places, but the answers were sparse. Particularly the solution seems to do with whether or not it is compiling in 32/64 bit, as this post suggests: [Undefined symbols: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleDocs"](https://groups.google.com/group/gdata-objectivec-client/browse_thread/thread/eb67c2b2edc3e565/3a352cdab90bba8f). However, I am not exactly understanding how to correct this, since this is my first time running into this problem, but I have checked that both the Architectures under PROJECT and TARGETS's Build Settings are

> Standard(armv7) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

thanks a lot!

p.s I am compiling it with iOS5.1 and Xcode 4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

How do you incorporate Google Docs API into your app? As the sources or as the static library?

"Particularly the solution seems to do with whether or not it is compiling in 32/64 bit" - your question has nothing to do with that since you are building an app for iOS